# Sort out only first item in multi array based on antoher id in array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I dont know how do to this.
See my array below.
I run this array in a while loop and need to find first `[attach_id]` for each `[topic_id]` and can use `$topic_id` that are set in the loop...

Correct output would be:
First loop:
`[attach_id] => 17989` (because this is the first `attach_id` for `topic_id 20890`)

and then
Second loop:
`[attach_id] => 17896` (because this is the first `attach_id` for `topic_id 20887`)

But I cant get it to work  ....

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array
( 
    [attach_id] => 17989 
    [post_msg_id] => 298566 
    [topic_id] => 20890 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 142437 
    [filetime] => 1442566541 
    [thumbnail] => 1
)
[1] => Array
( 
    [attach_id] => 17990 
    [post_msg_id] => 298566 
    [topic_id] => 20890 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 213432 
    [filetime] => 1442566541 
    [thumbnail] => 1
) 
[2] => Array 
(
    [attach_id] => 17991 
    [post_msg_id] => 298566 
    [topic_id] => 20890 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 63320 
    [filetime] => 1442566541 
    [thumbnail] => 1 
)
[3] => Array
( 
    [attach_id] => 17988 
    [post_msg_id] => 298566 
    [topic_id] => 20890 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 171560 
    [filetime] => 1442566540 
    [thumbnail] => 1
)
[4] => Array
(
    [attach_id] => 17896 
    [post_msg_id] => 298546 
    [topic_id] => 20887 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 304056 
    [filetime] => 1441372805 
    [thumbnail] => 1 
) 
[5] => Array
(
    [attach_id] => 17895 
    [post_msg_id] => 298546 
    [topic_id] => 20887  
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 125938 
    [filetime] => 1441372804 
    [thumbnail] => 1
)
[6] => Array 
(
    [attach_id] => 17894 
    [post_msg_id] => 298546 
    [topic_id] => 20887 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [mimetype] => image/jpeg 
    [filesize] => 328378 
    [filetime] => 1441372785 
    [thumbnail] => 1 
)
```

)

Comment: Perhaps create a for loop that collects all unique instances of `topic_id` into an array.  Then use another for loop to check if is the first instance of one of those in the newly created array and if so, grab it and delete that value from the array of `topic_id`.  Hope that this makes sense.

Comment: What can't you get to work? Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't know what your expected result exactly is, here are two possibilities:

```
$myArray = array (
    array (
        "attach_id" => 17989,
        "post_msg_id" => 298566,
        "topic_id" => 20890 ,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 142437,
        "filetime" => 1442566541,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array(
        "attach_id" => 17990,
        "post_msg_id" => 298566,
        "topic_id" => 20890,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 213432,
        "filetime" => 1442566541,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array (
        "attach_id" => 17991,
        "post_msg_id" => 298566,
        "topic_id" => 20890,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 63320,
        "filetime" => 1442566541,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array(
        "attach_id" => 17988,
        "post_msg_id" => 298566,
        "topic_id" => 20890,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 171560,
        "filetime" => 1442566540,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array(
        "attach_id" => 17896,
        "post_msg_id" => 298546,
        "topic_id" => 20887,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 304056,
        "filetime" => 1441372805,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array (
        "attach_id" => 17895,
        "post_msg_id" => 298546,
        "topic_id" => 20887,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 125938,
        "filetime" => 1441372804,
        "filetime" => 1,
    ),
    array(
        "attach_id" => 17894,
        "post_msg_id" => 298546,
        "topic_id" => 20887,
        "extension" => "jpg",
        "mimetype" => "image/jpeg",
        "filesize" => 328378,
        "filetime" => 1441372785,
        "filetime" => 1,
    )
);

$firstResultArray = array();

// creates a new array with two keys => topic_id and attach_id
foreach( $myArray as $array ) {
    if( isset( $firstResultArray[ $array["topic_id"] ] ) ) continue;
    $firstResultArray[ $array["topic_id"] ] = array( "attach_id" => $array["attach_id"], "topic_id" => $array["topic_id"] );
}
// re-index array
$firstResultArray = array_values( $firstResultArray );

// create new array with topic_id as index and attach_id as value
$secondResultArray = array();
foreach( $myArray as $array ) {
    if( isset( $secondResultArray[ $array["topic_id"] ] ) ) continue;
    $secondResultArray[ $array["topic_id"] ] = $array["attach_id"];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $firstResultArray );

var_dump( $secondResultArray );
```

OUTPUT:

```
// first version
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["attach_id"]=>
    int(17989)
    ["topic_id"]=>
    int(20890)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["attach_id"]=>
    int(17896)
    ["topic_id"]=>
    int(20887)
  }
}


//second version
array(2) {
  [20890]=>
  int(17989)
  [20887]=>
  int(17896)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$attachTopicId = array();
foreach($array as $subArray) {
    if (array_key_exists($subArray["topic_id"], $attachTopicId)) {
        if ($attachTopicId[$subArray["topic_id"]] < $subArray["attach_id"]) {
            $attachTopicId[$subArray["topic_id"]] = $subArray["attach_id"];
        }
    }
    else {
        $attachTopicId[$subArray["topic_id"]] = $subArray["attach_id"];
    }
}

// test output 
if (count($attachTopicId) > 0) {
    foreach($attachTopicId as $key => $value) {
        print sprintf("Topic ID: %s Attach ID: %s", $key, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$topicIdArray = [];
$foundAttachId = [];

foreach ($arrayToSearch as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists('topic_id', $value) {
        if (!in_array($value['topic_id'], $topicIdArray)) {
            if (array_key_exists('attach_id', $value) {
                $foundAttachId[] = $value['attach_id'];
                $topicIdArray[] = $value['topic_id'];
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($foundAttachId);
```

This should work