# PHP: Array Segregation By Index Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[
        {
          "id": "13216",
          "image_type": "ThumbnailImage",
          "is_primary": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "13217",
          "image_type": "MediumImage",
          "is_primary": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "13218",
          "image_type": "LargeImage",
          "is_primary": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "13219",
          "image_type": "ThumbnailImage",
          "is_primary": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "13220",
          "image_type": "MediumImage",
          "is_primary": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "13221",
          "image_type": "LargeImage",
          "is_primary": "0"
        }
]
```

I want to convert this into this:

```
[
    "ThumbnailImage" => [
            {
                "id": "13216",
                "image_type": "ThumbnailImage",
                "is_primary": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "13219",
                "image_type": "ThumbnailImage",
                "is_primary": "0"
            },
        ],
        "MediumImage" => [
            {
                "id": "13217",
                "image_type": "MediumImage",
                "is_primary": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "13220",
                "image_type": "MediumImage",
                "is_primary": "0"
            },
        ],
        "LargeImage" => [
            {
                "id": "13218",
                "image_type": "LargeImage",
                "is_primary": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "id": "13221",
                "image_type": "LargeImage",
                "is_primary": "0"
            }
        ]
]
```

I am looking for dynamic solution in which i can specify the key name and it automatically segregates the array based on the values of that index e.g. in this case if i specify the index name image_type it should give me the mentioned output and if i specify is_primary it should return index 0 and 1 with their values.

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
public function segregateByIndex($array, $segregateKey)
{
        $result = [];
        foreach( $array as $val ) {
            $result[$val[$segregateKey]][] = $val;
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: You have 3k rep and I still need to ask, what you have tried so far? For what is the php tag I only can see JSON?

Comment: This is array is shown for data structure understanding purpose. i know the syntax resembles JSON format.

Comment: Plus sometimes a person doesnt know where should it start from. I have tried to search a lot but couldnt find anything that resembles to this.

Comment: well slightly different, BUT you just have to drop the continue and push the values to the array (look at the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652651/sort-out-only-first-item-in-multi-array-based-on-antoher-id-in-array-php/32653293

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do except what it needs to look like :)

Comment: @swidmann in the OP's defense, just because his rep points are high doesnt mean he knows it all. He might be an expert on other languages, but not the greatest in JSON or arrays. However I do agree that he at least needs to submit what he has already tried.

Comment: @CodeGodie, sorry If someone got this wrong, I **only** wanted to point out to "I still need to ask, what you have tried so far". I have no problem at all with the question itself, except the missing effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy to solve using `foreach` like as

```
$result = [];
foreach(json_decode($your_json,true) as $key => $val){
    $result[$val['image_type']][] = $val;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Are you expecting something else. I'm pretty sure that this'll work

Comment: Yep I know that's why I've said I'm pretty sure that this'll work

Comment: I tried with changing the key name it didnt worked but i have made dynamic key. Thats why i accepted this again

Comment: why change it to a multidimensional array rather than an array of objects? and why use the `$key` variable if its not used?

Comment: Array's are faster and while answering I thought of another answer but I ended up with different @CodeGodie